# Java program that takes 6 numbers and a target number and prints the smallest possible difference

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to solve this task: Having 6 inputted numbers (range from 0 to 1000) in the first line and target number in the second, we need to find the closest number to the target number using only those numbers and basic operations *, -, / and +. Addition and Subtraction have priority and we can't use any parenthesis. The incomplete division is allowed and the final result can be a rational number. Each given number can be used only once. Each expression must contain at least one number and must be a valid mathematical expression. Concatenating the numbers together is not allowed.

We need to print the |target - closest| output value. The result will be considered correct if it differs from the exact value by less than 10^-6

The program should work like this:

```
Input:
1 2 3 4 5 6
21
Output:
0


Input:
16 65 83 61 33 64
934
Output:
0.0625
```

In the first test case, we just add up all the numbers and hit the target number 21 exactly.

In the second test case, we get the optimal result with the expression 65 + 83 + 33 + 64 / 16 * 61

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;


public class project {
  private static Set<Character> operations = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '*', '/'));
  private static double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
  private static String closestExpr = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] numbers = new double[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    double target = sc.nextDouble();

    char[] expr = new char[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (char operation : operations) {
        expr[i] = operation;
        permuteExpression(numbers, expr, 0, target);
      }
    }

    
    System.out.println(minDiff);
  }

  private static void permuteExpression(double[] numbers, char[] expr, int depth, double target) {
    if (depth == expr.length) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(numbers[0]);
      double result = numbers[0];
      for (int i = 0; i < expr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(expr[i]);
        sb.append(numbers[i + 1]);
        switch (expr[i]) {
          case '+':
            result += numbers[i + 1];
            break;
          case '-':
            result -= numbers[i + 1];
            break;
          case '*':
            result *= numbers[i + 1];
            break;
          case '/':
            result /= numbers[i + 1];
            break;
        }
      }
      double diff = Math.abs(result - target);
      if (diff < minDiff && diff < Math.pow(10, -6)) {
        minDiff = diff;
        closestExpr = sb.toString();
      }
      return;
    }

    for (char operation : operations) {
      expr[depth] = operation;
      permuteExpression(numbers, expr, depth + 1, target);
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, I have two errors: First is that my result is not close enough. When I test it on the server I'm trying to submit it fails for some many values, for example:

```
My output:
1.7976931348623157E308
<<<EOF>>>

Correct output:
0.0625<<<EOF>>>
```

Second, when the numbers are a bit large, the result is ALWAYS `1.7976931348623157E308`.

If anyone has any idea how to fix it please let me know, I'll appreciate any hint or advice.

Comment: Hi! Can you give a few test cases with expected results as part of your question?

Comment: This also might be some help, although it operates on integers rather than doubles: https://codinghelmet.com/exercises/expression-from-numbers

Comment: What does “Addition and Subtraction have priority ” mean?  You also don’t seem to do anything about it, which could be why you’re not getting the right answer..  Also, the nested `for` loops around the initial call in `main` (and that `expr[i] = operation` ) are worse than useless - get rid of them (permuteExpression itself does all the looping it needs)

Comment: Are you required to use all 6 of the numbers? Do you use each number exactly once?